# How many 'it' can we define inside a describe block?

Tags: protractor

I am using Protractor for e2e testing. I want to know, How many 'it' we can define inside a 'describe block' in a test file like below-

```
describe('This is my test suite',function(){

      it('This is my test case 1',function(){
      })
      it('This is my test case 2',function(){
      })
      it('This is my test case 3',function(){
      })
      it('This is my test case 4',function(){
      })
      ............

     it('This is my test case n',function(){
     })

})
```

What could be maximum value of n for this describe block?

Answer (score 3):

I don't recall any limitation to the number of `it` blocks per `describe` in Jasmine. But, even though there is no technical limitation, make sure *you don't hurt readability* by having many `it` blocks per describe.

Instead of putting tests into a single describe, organize your tests logically, use multiple `describe` blocks, use multiple files grouped per a test directory logically.

There is also [`jasmine-data-provider` project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider) which introduces a handy `using` keyword that allows to dynamically "multiply" tests based on different parameters.